# Why are there no ticks on my X (time) axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**QUESTION:**

Why are there no ticks on my X (time) axis `xAxis`?

---

**CODE:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">   
        d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json", function(error, json) {
          if (error) {
              return console.warn(error);
          }
          visualizeIt(json);
        });

        function visualizeIt(data) {
            const dataset = data.data;

            const  margin = {
                top: 10,
                right: 6,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 70
            }

            const w = 900 - margin.left - margin.right;
            const h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            const barWidth = Math.ceil(w / dataset.length);
            const format = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m");

            const  mindate = dataset[0][0];
            const  maxdate = dataset[274][0];

            const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain([mindate, maxdate])    
                .range([0, w]);   

            const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (d) => d[1])])
                .range([h, 0]);

            const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

            const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)

            const svg = d3.select("#results")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width",  w + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);


            svg.append("g")
               .attr("transform", "translate(50," + (h+margin.top) + ")")
               .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
               .attr("transform", "translate(50," + margin.top + ")")
               .call(yAxis);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", (d,i) => 50+barWidth*i)
               .attr("y", (d, i) => yScale(d[1]) + margin.top)
               .attr("width", barWidth)
               .attr("height", (d, i) => h - yScale(d[1]))
               .attr("fill", "navy")
               .attr("class", "bar");

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Possibly same reason there is no code in your question

Comment: @charlietfl Updated question

Comment: Unrelated to your question but 274 bars is not the best way to display this data. Consider using an Area or Line chart.

Comment: @sparta93 I agree. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code, but I'll address only those related to the x-axis ticks:

1. You want to **parse** the strings and return dates, not the other way around. Thus, instead of using `timeFormat`, your `conts format` should use `timeParse`:

   ```
   const format = d3.timeParse(specifier)
   ```
2. That brings us to the second problem: the specifier in your `const format` is wrong. You're missing `%d` here, which is the day, since your strings are like this: `"1947-01-01"`. So, it should be:

   ```
   const format = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
   ```
3. You have to use the parser in your dates:

   ```
   const  mindate = format(dataset[0][0]);
   ```

   Do the same for `maxdate`.

Here is your updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmjRzY?editors=1010

Comment: Hello ! Would you know the answer to this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636134/why-is-my-heatmap-not-correctly-showing-up

Comment: @Coder1000 I just answered.