# Why is my HeatMap not showing up correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**SITUATION IMAGE:**

[image]

---

**SITUATION:**

My heatMap D3.js graph does not show up correctly.

What have I done wrong ?

There are 0 errors in the console.

I can't find the bug. It's most probably something hidden in plain sight.

---

**CODE:**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">   
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json", function(error, json) {
      if (error) {
          return console.warn(error);
      }
      visualizeThe(json);
    });

    function visualizeThe(data) {

        const baseTemperature = data.baseTemperature;
        const tempData = data.monthlyVariance;

        const margin = {
            top: 10,
            right: 85,
            bottom: 45,
            left: 0
        }

        const w = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right;
        const h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        const barWidth = Math.ceil(w / tempData.length);

        const colors = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"];
        const buckets = colors.length;
        const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        const  minTime = d3.min(tempData, (d) => new Date(d.year,1,1,0,0));
        const  maxTime = d3.max(tempData, (d) => new Date(d.year,1,1,0,0));

        const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([minTime, maxTime])    
            .range([0, w]);   

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(20);

        const svg = d3.select("#results")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",  w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        const div = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")  
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(70," + (h+margin.top) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        const monthsLabels = svg.selectAll("monthLabel")
            .data(months)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text((d) => d)
            .attr("x", 100)
            .attr("y", (d,i) => i * h/12 + 30)
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-40," +0+ ")")
            .style("font-size", 10);

        const colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
            .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(tempData, (d) => d.variance + baseTemperature )])
            .range(colors);

        const heatMap = svg.selectAll("month")
            .data(tempData, (d) => d)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d,i) => i * barWidth + 60)
            .attr("y", (d) => d.month * h/12 - 440)
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("height", h/12)
            .style("fill", colors[0]);

        heatMap.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.variance + baseTemperature));


//          heatMap.exit().remove();



        svg.append("text")             
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + (w/2) + " ," + 
                (h+ margin.top + 45) + ")")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Years");

        svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", -5)
            .attr("x",0 - (h / 2))
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Months");       
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `svg.selectAll("month")` as it is not selecting anything. What are you trying to select there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems so far:

1. Your xScale range is wrong, it should be:

   ```
    .range([margin.left, w]);
   ```
2. You are hardcoding the x position of the x axis;
3. Your rectangles' y position have a wrong magic number;
4. You have to use the xScale for positioning your rectangles:

   ```
   .attr("x", (d) => xScale(new Date(d.year,1,1,0,0)))
   ```

Although the best idea here is creating a parser to convert `d.year` to a date.

Also, I'm increasing the width of the rectangles, from 1px to 2px.

Here is your updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmONrK?editors=1000

Comment: Here's the latest state of the codepen after your suggestion and some modifications: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwoVBQ and here is what I am trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/aNLYPp/

Comment: If I replace the current color Scheme with the correct one, the result is this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjRePE For some reason, the result is very different, I am trying to figure how without looking at the answer.

Comment: Please, if you have *another* problem, post *another* question. Besides that, acknowledge people trying to help you. If you don't, people simply stop helping. That being said, here is your code with the correct color scale: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmWWdv

Comment: I agree with you, who did I miss ? On another note, this is exactly the problem I described before, if I change the color scheme to the correct one, I do not get the correct graph, please have  a look at the differences: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/aNLYPp/  I will ask another question.

Comment: Here is the separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656494/why-is-the-color-distribution-different-on-my-d3-heatmap

Comment: Good, it's always a good practice keeping 1 problem per question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmqeWR

The lines I changed:

```
.attr("x", (d,i) => (i-d.month) * barWidth + 70)
.attr("y", (d) => (d.month * h/12 -30))
.attr("width", barWidth*12)
```

Note that this may not be accurate (that is, the correct data may not line up with the correct year), since I'm not sure how you set it all up. I just fiddled with it until I got the chart to display, you can debug it from here.

Comment: Just a tip: you should have 262 rectangles for each month.